# Small text in new window after launching exe with shift+enter in FAR

Tags: conemu

Sometimes I need to launch exe or bat file in separate window, I always did it with `shift+enter`.

On Win7 there was no issues, now I have switched to Win10, and when I launch program via `shift+enter` I see window like that

[image]

Changing its "defaults" doesn't remember settings, I could change font size for this particular window if I click conemu icon and choose properties, but that is not the way to go.

Comment: Use macro to start new command in ConEmu window. What you see is standard "conhost". There's no sense to change "defaults", console properties are saved by executable path directly and defaults are just ignored by Windows

Comment: @Maximus Thanks for your answer, I found how to add macro for `shift+enter` with command `Shell("open","cmd.exe","/k")`. How do I replace `cmd.exe` with currently selected file under my cursor in FAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with macro #3

it basically type into FAR command line `start CTRL+Enter enter`, ctrl+enter paste currently selected file in FAR into command line

[image]

**Updated**:

Recently it stopped working again, so I have to change macro to this

`print("\ecmd/c start cmd /c "); Keys("^Enter"); print("\n")`

[image]